# How can I Measure Hibernate/JPA SQL Queries min, max and average Execution time With Actuator

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot-actuator

I Want to Monitor My Spring boot Application with Actuator but I Can't Find any Way to Calculate SQL Queries Min/Max/Average Time.

I used `hibernate.generate_statistics` but it didn't capture Sql queries Execution time.

Is there a Hibernate Micrometer Available for this Purpose?

Answer (score 1):

There is a micrometer integration available: https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-micrometer/5.5.4.Final/jar

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to add hibernate-micrometer dependency and use SpringBoot 2.5.x or newer. No additional configuration is necessary.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find alternative for older SpringBoot and myself could not make it work just with 5.5.5 on SpringBoot 2.4.x